# Grouping and Computing Frequency ,Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I have a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['Pokemon', 'Pokemon', 'Bird', 'Pokemon', 'Bird', 'Pokemon', 'Pokemon', 'Bird'],'Name' : ['Jerry', 'Jerry', 'Flappy Bird', 'Mudkip','Pigeon', 'Mudkip', 'Jerry', 'Pigeon']})
```

and i need to group the observations w.r.t their types i.e all pokemon types together with their respective names . And i need to add another column which has the frequency of occurrence of the names in the types. It should look like :

```
Type         Name     Frequency   
Pokemon      Jerry        3 
             Mudkip       2    

Bird         Pigeon       2  
           Flappy Bird    1
```

I used :

```
data2 = df.groupby(['Type'])
```

but that doesn't group it the way it needs to be.
Please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I  think you want to group on both 'Type' and 'Name':

```
print df.groupby(['Type','Name']).size()

Type     Name       
Bird     Flappy Bird    1
         Pigeon         2
Pokemon  Jerry          3
         Mudkip         2
```

Or if it is important to have the column named 'Frequency', you could do something like the following:

```
print df.groupby(['Type','Name'])['Type'].agg({'Frequency':'count'})

                     Frequency
Type    Name                  
Bird    Flappy Bird          1
        Pigeon               2
Pokemon Jerry                3
        Mudkip               2
```

Comment: Could i create a dictionary from the above group ?? the key "Bird" will have a value of list containing ['Pigeon',Flappy Bird'] note that higher frequency should appear first..

Comment: How can I get ratio instead of frequency? For example, for this case, the column will be 1/3, 2/3, 3/5, 2/5.

Comment: found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710690/percentage-of-a-multiindex-in-pandas  :)