# Count frequency of a number in a column while equals to text in another column

Tags: python, pandas

This is from sample csv

Roughly it looks like this 5 columns

Clipboard:

```
Year  Course  Modul Q1 Q2
2015 Physics CS1203  4  2 
2015 Physics CS1203  4  3 
2015 Physics CS1203  3  1 
2015 Physics CS1203  4  4 
2015 English IR0001  2  5 
2015 English IR0001  1  2 
2015 English IR0001  3  1 
2015 English IR0001  5  3 
2015 English IR0001  4  3
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I grouped by modules, now i want to count number of 4s in module CS1203. I am new at this, so sorry in advance if this is stupid question. I really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add image as text to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[(df.module == 'CS1203') & (df.q1 == 4)])
   year   course  module  q1  q2
0  2015  Physics  CS1203   4   2
1  2015  Physics  CS1203   4   3
3  2015  Physics  CS1203   4   4

print (len(df[(df.module == 'CS1203') & (df.q1 == 4)]))
3
```

If need count in all `q` columns first use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['year','course','module'], value_name='q')
   year   course  module  q1  q2
0  2015  Physics  CS1203   4   2
1  2015  Physics  CS1203   4   3
2  2015  Physics  CS1203   3   1
3  2015  Physics  CS1203   4   4
4  2015  English  IR0001   2   5
5  2015  English  IR0001   1   2
6  2015  English  IR0001   3   1
7  2015  English  IR0001   5   3
8  2015  English  IR0001   4   3

print (df[(df.module == 'CS1203') & (df.q == 4)])
    year   course  module variable  q
0   2015  Physics  CS1203       q1  4
1   2015  Physics  CS1203       q1  4
3   2015  Physics  CS1203       q1  4
12  2015  Physics  CS1203       q2  4

print (len(df[(df.module == 'CS1203') & (df.q == 4)]))
4
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael for your help yesterday, you response was very helpful. However, I came across another problem and would really appreciate your help. The above csv file - I want to create a function - when we run the script it asks us to enter module code. If module code equal to our module in the list than sum length of 4 and 5 and divide by total*100.
When a user enters a module code the script should return percentage value. Can you please help me, how can i do that? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can first filter your DF by module (`df.module == 'CS1203'`), then filter columns selecting only those matching `q\d+` RegEx, select only `4`s and finally calculate the sum:

```
In [74]: (df[df.module == 'CS1203'].filter(regex=r'q\d+') == 4).sum()
Out[74]:
q1    3
q2    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
df.groupby(['module','q1'])['module'].agg({'Frequency':'count'})
```

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402150/grouping-and-computing-frequency-pandas).