# Percentage of a multiindex in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to find the percentage of a MultiIndex column ('count'). My DataFrame looks like:

```
            count
A  week1     264

   week2      29

B  week1     152

   week2      15
```

and I'd like to add a column 'percent' to make

```
            count percent
A  week1     264      0.9

   week2      29      0.1

B  week1     152     0.91

   week2      15     0.09
```

I know that I can find the totals I want by

```
mydf.sum(level=[0, 1])
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to turn this into a percentage.

Comment: How about `df['percent'] = df['count'] / df['count'].sum()` ?

Comment: the df is a multi-index - it's organised by the first two columns. I want the percentage of A over both weeks. 'df['count'] / df['count'].sum(level=['things', 'weeks])' gives an error

Comment: ah ok, it looks like @cmaher has a solution

Comment: @TomKealy I have add a method without groupby if you interested :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['percent'] = df.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: (x / x.sum()).round(2))

#          count  percent
# A week1    264     0.90
#   week2     29     0.10
# B week1    152     0.91
#   week2     15     0.09
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That's 2 hours of my life!

Comment: Have adding a method without groupby

Answer (score 8):

Without groupby

```
df['percentage']=df['count'].div(df['count'].sum(level=0),level=0)
df
Out[128]: 
         count  percentage
x b                       
A week1    264    0.901024
  week2     29    0.098976
B week1    152    0.910180
  week2     15    0.089820
```

Comment: +1 you can avoid specifying the column in this case (`df.div(df.sum(level=0), level=0)`), since there's only the one.